# Unity hangs on successful connection using Socket.ConnectAsync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sockets

I have a very simple TCPClient and TCPServer setup which works as expected in Console Applications, however when porting the client code to Unity, the program hangs on `socket.ConnectAsync` when connecting to the server.

Client class:

```cs
public class TCPClient {
    private ArraySegment<byte> buffer;
    private Socket? socket;

    public delegate void onReceive_delegate(int bytesReceived, EndPoint endpoint);
    public onReceive_delegate? onReceive;

    public TCPClient(ArraySegment<byte> buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    private void Open() {
        if (socket != null) Dispose();
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    }

    public async Task Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) {
        Open();
        await socket!.ConnectAsync(remoteEP); // Hangs here for some reason
        _ = Listen();
    }

    private async Task Listen() {
        if (socket == null) return;

        int receivedBytes = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        onReceive?.Invoke(receivedBytes, socket.RemoteEndPoint!);

        _ = Listen();
    }

    public void Disconnect() {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (socket == null) return;

        socket.Dispose();
        socket = null;
    }
}
```

Code that performs the connection

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        TCPClient client = new TCPClient(buffer);

        // _ = client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 54892)); 
        // ^=> this does not cause editor to hang, which is to be expected

        client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 54892)).Wait(); 
        // ^=> causes editor to hang, however I don't think it should 
        //     because on successful connection, socket.ConnectAsync 
        //     should return and therefore not hang, but this is 
        //     not the case.
    }
}
```

Note that in the unity code I wish for it to hang until a successful connection is made. The problem is that it hangs indefinitely even after a successful connection is made (server logs that it accepted the connection etc...).

Also when using the exact same client code in a separate console application, it does not hang. It only hangs indefinitely in unity editor. (I have not tested build yet).

Further more, using the blocking function, `socket.Connect`, instead of `await socket.ConnectAsync` causes the intended behaviour of blocking until successful connection then continuing as normal.

Unity version 2022.3.12f1

Comment: I have a [blog post that explains this behavior](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary Yup that does explain it! Thank you so much, your blog cleared it up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Does anything speak against using the "normal" [`TcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) instead of implementing your own?

Anyway in general: You are literally explicitly forcing the Unity thread to `Wait()` until the `client.Connect` task is finished => of course it will freeze.

You probably rather wanted to properly go `async` and do

```
private async void Start()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    TCPClient client = new TCPClient(buffer);

    await client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 54892)); 

    // Do stuff once connected
}
```

which is fully supported in Unity.

You might also take a look at [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) which provides some neat seem less async integrations specific to Unity

Comment: If you fully read my question you will notice that I mentioned it hangs on successful connection. After the connection succeeds the task should complete and thus Wait() will follow through.

Comment: I want it to block until the connection is made, but even after the connection is made it continues to hang.